# moq 4.5.29 -getting error " type initializer for 'Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory' threw an exception."

Tags: moq, xunit

I am using xUnit 2.x and moq 4.5 and castle.core 3.3.0.0 . I have the IAssessmentsRepository interface in a different assembly ( but part of same solution) than my unit test are. I am giving reference to the assembly where IAssessmentsRepository reside. But when I try to mock, it gets error of "Type initilization"  which means that moq is not able to load the type i.e. IAssessmentsRepository .  Now I do not understand why ?? kindly suggest if anyone faced the same issue.

```
  [Fact]
            [UnitTest]
            public void DeleteAssessment_ShouldCall_AssessmentsRepository_DeleteAssessment_Method()
            {
                //Arrange
                var assessmentRepoMock = new Mock<Data.Assessments.IAssessmentsRepository>();
                assessmentRepoMock.Setup(x => x.DeleteAssessment(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

                var assessmentService = new AssessmentService(assessmentRepoMock.Object);

                //Act
                var testResult = assessmentService.DeleteAssessment(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>());

                //Assert

                assessmentRepoMock.Verify(r => r.DeleteAssessment(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);

            }
```

following is the stack trace of the error,

```
 UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests.UnitTests.AssessmentServiceTests.DeleteAssessment_ShouldCall_AssessmentsRepository_DeleteAssessment_Method [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6027020]       System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Moq.Mock`1' threw an exception.
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6033988]       ---- System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory' threw an exception.
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6038240]       -------- System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Configuration system failed to initialize
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6042223]       ------------ System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element. (C:\DEV2\LouisFinal\UpdatedOne\UHCNV.WEB.SERVICES.ICM\test\UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests\bin\x86\Debug\UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests.dll.config line 23)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6113488]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6119217]            at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__24_0()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6123448]            at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6127299]            at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6131116]            at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6134937]            at Moq.Mock.GetObject()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6138850]            at Moq.Mock.get_Object()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6142657]            at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6146855]         test\UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests\UnitTests\AssessmentServiceTests.cs(20,0): at UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests.UnitTests.AssessmentServiceTests.DeleteAssessment_ShouldCall_AssessmentsRepository_DeleteAssessment_Method()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6150651]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6154568]            at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6158157]            at Moq.Mock`1..cctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6161683]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6165556]            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6169380]            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6173346]            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6177103]            at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6180813]            at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6184595]            at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6188321]            at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_Sources()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6191972]            at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6195693]            at Castle.Core.Logging.TraceLogger.IsSourceConfigured(TraceSource source)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6199486]            at Castle.Core.Logging.TraceLogger.Initialize()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6204199]            at Castle.Core.Logging.TraceLogger..ctor(String name, LoggerLevel level)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6208012]            at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator..ctor(IProxyBuilder builder)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6211584]            at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6215447]            at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxyGenerator()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6219298]            at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory..cctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6222921]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6226725]            at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6230535]            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6242699]            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6247423]            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6633781]     UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests.UnitTests.AssessmentServiceTests.GenerateAssessmentForm_ShouldCall_AssessmentsRepository_GenerateAssessmentForm_Method [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6715323]       System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Moq.Mock`1' threw an exception.
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6719637]       ---- System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory' threw an exception.
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6723726]       -------- System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Configuration system failed to initialize
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6727605]       ------------ System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element. (C:\DEV2\LouisFinal\UpdatedOne\UHCNV.WEB.SERVICES.ICM\test\UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests\bin\x86\Debug\UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests.dll.config line 23)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6796134]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6801181]            at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__24_0()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6805315]            at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6809086]            at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6813035]            at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6816928]            at Moq.Mock.GetObject()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6820733]            at Moq.Mock.get_Object()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6824593]            at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6828478]         test\UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests\UnitTests\AssessmentServiceTests.cs(40,0): at UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests.UnitTests.AssessmentServiceTests.GenerateAssessmentForm_ShouldCall_AssessmentsRepository_GenerateAssessmentForm_Method()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6832594]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6836425]            at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6841577]            at Moq.Mock`1..cctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6845556]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6856442]            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6860674]            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6864632]            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6869201]            at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6873166]            at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6877093]            at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6881252]            at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_Sources()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6885259]            at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6889303]            at Castle.Core.Logging.TraceLogger.IsSourceConfigured(TraceSource source)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6893368]            at Castle.Core.Logging.TraceLogger.Initialize()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6897193]            at Castle.Core.Logging.TraceLogger..ctor(String name, LoggerLevel level)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6901234]            at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator..ctor(IProxyBuilder builder)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6905143]            at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6909231]            at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxyGenerator()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6913291]            at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory..cctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6917210]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6921119]            at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6925092]            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6929139]            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.6933131]            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.7185612]   Finished:    UHCNV.Web.Services.Icm.Services.Tests
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the root cause of the issue which is kind of weird. It was related to my `app.config` file in the test project. My `app.config` was as below when I was facing the issue:

```xml
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

All I needed to do was to make sure `configSections` tag would be the first child of my root element so I updated my `app.config` file as below:

```xml
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

And voila, problem resolved. The error message was so confusing.